# Duplicated assets in .jar file created by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, assets

I have an android studio project, the project has an application module and a library module. The application module is simply a demo of the library module. The library module depends on a third party, for the sake of simplicity, let's call it `external.jar`.

Android studio could successfully build the library module, generate a library named `classes.jar`.

I noticed that android studio also copied assets from `external.jar` into `classes.jar` along with .class files. The problem emerged when I was trying to build an apk from the application module, because the application module depends on `external.jar`, android studio refused to assemble the final apk due to duplicated assets, and showed the following error message:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK assets/ap1.data
>       File1: /Users/skyrim/android/Demo/app/libs/classes.jar
>       File2: /Users/skyrim/android/Demo/app/libs/external.jar

I have to release the library module in binary form to third parties, they may also use `classes.jar` along with `external.jar`, so excluding unnecessary assets is a must.

The following is my library module's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

How can I prevent android studio from copying assets from `external.jar` into `classes.jar` ? Of course, I can simply unzip `classes.jar` and move unnecessary assets and re-zip it, but I prefer some less hackish solutions.

I'm new to android development and gradle build system, any suggestions are welcome.